# how to extend the border of a class over other classes

Tags: css, class, html, border, extend

I would like the border around the friends class to extend the whole distance from the persons name to the add friends class.

**HTML**

```
<div class = 'friends'> Persons Name</div>
    <div class = 'buttons'> add as friend </div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .friends {  
           border: 1px solid;
           display: inline;
           }
 .buttons  {
           background-color:blue;  
           float: right; 
           width: 50px;
           display: inline;
           }
```

I have [added a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZR36K/5/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Can you chance the markup, for instance place div buttons inside div friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class = 'friends'> Persons Name
    <div class = 'buttons'> add as friend </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.friends {
         border: 1px solid;
         display: block;
         width: 100%;
         }

.buttons {
         background-color:blue; 
         float: right;  
         display: inline;
         }
```

I think that it what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/ZR36K/6/) solution comes to mind, if you can set the height of the elements.

Comment: The OP didn't give much specifics. If you downvote, be so kind as to share what was the perceived faultyness in my answer.